# Fermat's Last Theorem solved through induction on $z$, not on $n$

Tags: number-theory

> Assume that we have shown a proof for the case $z=1$ and $z=2$ for $x^n +y^n = z^n$.
>
> Can we say that via mathematical induction on $z$ that this is now true for all integers $z$ for $n>2?$

Comment: How would you do the induction step? Clearly the base case $x^n+y^n=1$ is easy.

Comment: Can you prove it for $z=1?$

Comment: We can safely assume that if Fermat's last theorem could be solved via induction on $z$ , the theorem would have been proven long before Andrew Wiles's proof. Concluding from $z=1$ and $z=2$ to all $z$ is of course not possible : Simple example : $1$ and $2$ are divisors of $4$. Does that mean that all positive integers are divisors of $4$ ? Of course, no.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this isn't quite how proof by induction works.

Call $P$ whatever we're proving about $z$. We can't simply say "$P$ is true for $z=1$ and $z=2$, therefore it's true for all $z>2$". (For example, "$z<3$" is true for both of them but false for $z>2$.)

To prove $P$ by induction we have to show that **$P$ being true for one case forces it to be true for the next.** *Then* we say 'Well it's true for $z=1$ so it must be true for $z=2$, so it must be true for $z=3$, so . . . " and let this count its way through all the remaining positive integers. But we've not got infinitely long in which to do the counting, so we compress that into " so by induction, it's true for all $z\geq 1$".

The key point is that each case must prove the next one, so there's a chain all the way up from a case that we already know to be true.

So I'm afraid your proof needs to do rather more.

Comment: +1, although "this isn't quite how proof by induction works" is putting it rather mildly ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ithink "do rather more" is mild too given how much effort Andrew Wiles had to put in!

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical induction isn't "It works for $1$, it works for $2$, so it always works." You have to prove that the statement in question being true for $k$ implies that it is also true for $k+1$ - **for any value of $k$** (or [an equivalent variant of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction)).

What you seem to be doing is assuming that the induction step is *given as proved already*, which isn't the case - usually in fact this is precisely the nontrivial part of a proof by induction.

So no, you cannot say anything about FLT.

Comment: Case z=1 gives 1^n +1^n /= 1^n , 1^n+2^n /=1^n, 2^n+3^n /= 1^n FLT is true for z=1 whatever the value for n and x, y integers. This is the basis step.

Comment: @azdin And the induction step is ... what, precisely? Wishful thinking?

Comment: Induction step: We assume FLT is true until z=(p-1) and we must proove that FLT is true for z=p. The case z=(p-1) implies the case z=p.

Comment: @azdin "... and we must proove ..." yes, **you must prove**. Having not actually done that, you **cannot** say that FLT is proved. "The case z=(p-1) implies the case z=p." - how do you know that?

Comment: I can say that FLT is proved because I have done it . I demonstrate  that the case z=(p-1) implies z=p . I will send the proof  in the next post in order to be reviewed by mathematicians and followers.

Comment: Assume FLT is true until z=(p-1), we must prove that FLT is true for z=p
case z=p-1 gives 3 types for (x^n+y^n).
(x^n+y^n) < (p-1)^n then they are also < p^n.  satisfy FLT for z=p
(x^n+y^n) > p^n . satisfy FLT for z=p
(x^n+y^n) > (p-1)^n.  these sums are either < p^n or > p^n but never equal  p^n. 
    
 these sums follow the form (p-r)^n + k^n  
(p-r)^n= p^n –np^(n-1) r + n(n+1)/2 p^(n-2) r^2 .+/- r^n  
(p-r)^n + k^n = p^n + k^n – R
If (k^n-R)>0 then (p-r)^n + k^n > p^n else  (p-r)^n + k^n < p^n
These sums (p-r)^n + k^n satisfy FLT for z=p  Suppose  (p-r)^n + k^n = p^n

Comment: Suppose  (p-r)^n + k^n = p^n 
p^n – (p-r)^n=n [ p^(n-1) r - (n-1)/2 p^(n-2) r^2….+/-(r^n)/n ]    assume k= p-j 
k^n= (p-j)^n=(p-j) * (p-j)^(n-1)=(p-j) * [p^(n-1) –(n-1) p^(n-2) j …..+/-j^(n-1)] 
k^n/(p-j) and  (p^n –(p-r)^n) are 2  polynoms  p order (n-1)  
If n =/ (p-j) Let t to normalize two expressions to have n/t=p-j and equality of term (n-1).
p^n – (p-r)^n=(r n/t)*  t [  p^(n-1) – r * (n-1)/2 p^(n-2)..+/-(r^(n-1)/n ]
k^n= (p-j) * t [p^(n-1) –(n-1) p^(n-2) u ..+/-u^(n-1)]
(n*r) / t= (p-j) and (r^(n-1))/n =u^(n-1)
u = r / n^(n-1) is irrational for n>2  it is (n-1)th root of n

Comment: So  u = r / n^(n-1) is irrational for n>2 because it is (n-1)th root of n . It cannot be an integer which proves that  (p^n – (p-r)^n) cannot be equal to k^n.
All the sums (x^n+y^n) are not equal to p^n for all x, y and n>2.
FLT is true until  z=(p-1) implies FLT is true for z=p
 Conclusion
With the principle of strong mathematical induction, we can then conclude that the equation
x^n+y^n=p^n has no solutions in positive integers x, y and p whatever n > 2.

Comment: the proof is it readable? Your comment is noticeable. Thanks.